# How to prevent my $('form').submit(function(event)) from being applied to certain forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a dynamic page with many different forms and use  `$('form').submit(function(event)` to process the form after it is submitted.  I need to prevent the script from being applied to upload type forms because they are handled differently.  Is there a way to do this?  Thanks!

My Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(event) {

    //processes stuff

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your forms different classes with CSS and then you can target the ones you want specifically when you call the submit function.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.process').submit(function(event) {

    //processes stuff

    });
});

<form class='process'>
</form>
```

Comment: Similarly, you could just add it to forms you don't want to submit if you don't want to go back and change everything- with something like:

`$('form').not('.process').submit(function(){...});`

Specifically, if OP has 50 forms already, and only wants to exclude one of them.